# There is a higher energy 2Σ+ state with a bond length of 1.15 Å for CN molecule, explain this

Tags: physical-chemistry, spectroscopy

[image: Term symbol and bond lengths for CN]

How can there be an excited state for CN where the bond length is lower (stronger bond) than the actual ground state? The molecular orbital diagram suggests that the single electron in the sigma orbital gets excited, but to which orbital? This was a question asked by one of my professors and I don't know where to start, I think that the ground state X 2Σ+ goes to the B 2Σ+ excited state and maybe the electron could go to the 3S orbital? but then how would this affect the bond long is beyond me. In addition, would the vibrational fine structure go from V'=0 to V'=2? Can anyone help?

Comment: The inter-atomic potential has a minimum at some distance - this is the ground state bond length. Higher energy states will sample other parts of the inter-atomic potential, both at larger distances as well as small distances.

Comment: Do you understand how to derive the term symbols for a diatomic molecule? You should start by 1) drawing a MO diagram for CN; 2) figuring out which electronic excited configuration can correspond to a $^2\Sigma^+$ term symbol. There's no "3s" orbital in a diatomic molecule. As for the bond length, it is quite a straightforward concept: if you fill more bonding orbitals, then the equilibrium bond length decreases, and vice versa if you fill more antibonding orbitals.

Comment: However, note that a shorter equilibrium bond length does *not* necessarily mean more stable. Excited states can easily have shorter equilibrium bond lengths than ground states. It also does *not* necessarily imply a stronger bond. If you can draw a simple Morse potential curve, you will see that the bond strength (which is a vertical parameter) and the equilibrium bond length (which is a horizontal parameter) are quite different things.

Comment: @orthocresol I was thinking exciting one of the the 2s sigma star electrons to the 2p sigma orbital, I assume this would give the desired term symbol; however I'm unsure if this is a viable option

Comment: Okay, one thing about the MO labels. The sigma-type orbitals contain quite a good mixture of 2s and 2p orbitals. (For more details consult any text on the MO diagram of CO.) So, it's usually more common (and more accurate!) to label them $1\sigma$, $2\sigma$, $3\sigma$, $4\sigma$ without mentioning which atomic orbitals they arise from. I guess, you are referring to a $2\sigma \to 3\sigma$ promotion; indeed, that seems quite plausible to me. It would not be the first excited state (you already know that is a $^2\Pi$ term); it would be a higher excited state.

Comment: Hmm, and was that what you meant by "3S" in your question? I interpreted it as a 3s atomic orbital, sorry... You can typeset mathematical and chemical expressions on chem.SE using MathJax; [this post](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86) contains further details.

Comment: Bond lengths shorter than in the ground state are known in a few other molecules $\ce{C_2}$ and NO for example. The MO construction can only indicate  the number of bonding /anti-bonding/non-bonding orbitals are occupied and  one can then surmise about relative bond length changes when electrons are promoted to higher levels. Note that each excited state has its own set of vibrational & rotation levels. The particular geometry a molecule has determines which of these are excited when an new excited state is formed say by absorbing a photon. Selection rules determine which states are reached.